# In ReactJS, is it true that using a variable in the global scope of the file only works the same as useRef() when there is only one such component?

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

In ReactJS, when we write a functional component:

```js
let someState = true;

const Foo = (props) => {
  // so something...
  return <div> ... </div>;
}
```

We can use a "state" like above, or we can use `someStateByRef = useRef(true)` and `someStateByRef.current`.  (this is a state or a flag which does not need to be rendered or trigger re-rendering).

Are they the same, only when we are certain we will have one such component instance on the page?  It seems if there are two `Foo` instances, then the `someState` could be shared between the two components, while `someStateByRef.current` is one copy per `Foo`?  Does it work this way?

Comment: The biggest difference using the state like the code in the question and with the refs, react doesn't recognize it is changing, and will not update. You can even use window.myVar = 'something' and read it elsewhere. But react won't know if that changes, and won't re-render if it does.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same, because `useRef`'s scope is the component lifecycle.

This means that whenever the component is unmounted the `useRef` is removed and when the component mounts again you will have a new instance. E.g. when you conditionally render.

In contrast the `someState` will still exists after the component is unmounted.

If you have multiple instances of the `Foo` component, each one will have it's own instance of `useRef`, beacause it is bound to the components lifecycle.

```
 <Foo title="Foo"/>
 <Foo title="Bar"/>
```

So finally...

> It seems if there are two Foo instances, then the someState could be shared between the two components, while someStateByRef.current is one copy per Foo? Does it work this way?

Yes, it would work this way. But I would recommend to use a context if you want to share state between multiple components - see [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Comment: oh right, I don't want to share the state...  this component is the one-and-only component, so I think there is no worry... but if for any reason, the component needs to be displayed twice, then it'd become an issue